# ValueError: Only call `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` with named arguments (labels=..., logits=..., ...)

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

Can you guide how to fix this?

```
with tf.name_scope('loss'):
    #cross_entropy = None
    val = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y_conv, y_)
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(val)

with tf.name_scope('adam_optimizer'):
    #train_step = None
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-f67d0aecc114> in <module>()
      1 with tf.name_scope('loss'):
      2     #cross_entropy = None
----> 3     val = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y_conv, y_)
      4     cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(val)
      5 

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py in softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(_sentinel, labels, logits, dim, name)
   1576   """
   1577   _ensure_xent_args("softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits", _sentinel,
-> 1578                     labels, logits)
   1579 
   1580   # TODO(pcmurray) Raise an error when the labels do not sum to 1. Note: This

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py in _ensure_xent_args(name, sentinel, labels, logits)
   1531   if sentinel is not None:
   1532     raise ValueError("Only call `%s` with "
-> 1533                      "named arguments (labels=..., logits=..., ...)" % name)
   1534   if labels is None or logits is None:
   1535     raise ValueError("Both labels and logits must be provided.")

ValueError: Only call `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` with named arguments (labels=..., logits=..., ...)
```

Also, `tf.__version__` returns `'1.0.0'`
and I have `Anaconda Python 3.6.2` on OSX Sierra.

Comment: Does `y_conv` is None or returned or defined by other code? See this issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11942

Comment: excuse me , did you solve it ?

Answer (score 8):

This is an easy fix: `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()` has three key arguments: `_sentinel`, `labels`, and `logits`. The sentinel must be empty, requiring the use of named arguments.

Fixed (although I'm not sure if `y_conv` or `y_` is the label or logit in this case, so you may have to swap them):

```
with tf.name_scope('loss'):
    #cross_entropy = None
    val = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = y_conv, logits=y_)
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(val)

with tf.name_scope('adam_optimizer'):
    #train_step = None
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
```

Comment: why would I need to swap them Evan?

Comment: Think about what the cross entropy function calculates. At its core, it takes two probability distributions and calculates the "distance" between them, allowing you to get them closer to one another. For this use, one distribution is the softmax vector (logits), and the second is the one-hot label. I'm not sure if `y-conv` or `y_` is the softmax or one-hot label, so I took a random guess in the code.

Comment: I got this error after changing to what you said ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients, between variables ["<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(32,) dtype=float32_ref